# Why do calculated and read-out RGB-Values differ?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, color-management

**In short:**

1. Generate Mesh and choose color in color picker for the whole mesh (The mesh in the example below is a simple cube)
2. Read color (three float values) via Python and send them (with mesh details and uv-map ect) to a C++-Application
3. C++-Application creates a image which should be used as a texture

**Problem:**

The color, which is shown in the color picker isn't the same as the color of the texture.

I use the three float values, calculate the values between 0 and 255 and set the rgb-channels. Then the image is saved.

Some Screenshots:

**color picker with rgb**

[image: color picker with rgb]

RGB-Values via GIMP:

- R = 184
- G = 119
- B = 255

RGB-Values calculated and rounded: (255 * value)

- R = 0.479 * 255 = 122
- G = 0.184 * 255 = 47
- B = 1.0 * 255 = 255

**They aren't the same?**

**Generated Texture**

[image]

RGB-Values via GIMP:

- R = 122
- G = 47
- B = 255

**Renderen with Blender Cycles**

And now a Screenshot from the Mesh + Texture rendered via Cycles (with Ambient Occlusion). I removed the default lamp because I wan't to get a clean output.

[image]

RGB-Values of the color picker via GIMP (same as above):

- R = 184
- G = 119
- B = 255

RGB-Values of the cube via GIMP:

- R = 125
- G = 48
- B = 255

What is the problem?

PS: I didn't know which tags I should use for this question. So please remove or add tags if you think that would be better. Thanks!

Comment: It might be because you're not using the color in the same color space Blender is using, _or_ because Blender gamma corrects the colors.

Comment: So I need to undo the gamma correction, create the texture with the new rgb-values and blender is adding gamma correction when the image is loaded?

Comment: I _think_ so, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values differ because the rgb-values of the **color picker aren't gamma corrected**.

If I correct them like answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17910665/3069477 the colors are matching. I still get different RGB-Values but the difference is really small (rounding error).

**Resulting Screenshot:**

[image]

Thanks @someonewithpc!